# Drilldown in HighChart on Double Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, highcharts

I want to implement HighChart in **Drilldown mode** which would transition from *Column chart to Pie Chart* on **Double click of the column** *(double tap in case of mobile)*.
I am able to modify the drilldown demo provided by Highchart to display content & transition between Column & Pie charts on Single Click.
The running example can be seen at [Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/rckahale/kGSXL/1).

I have tried the following two ways to perform chart transition on double click. In `plotOptions.series.point.events.click`, a double click is identified if the two clicks fall within the gap of 500ms.

1)  `this.series.data[0].firePointEvent('click');`

This click is being triggered for first chart, but Pie Chart is not shown on click.

2)

```
this.drilldown= {series: drilldownSeries};
$('.highcharts-drilldown').onclick()
```

or any dom event, with

```
chart.drilldown: { series: drilldownSeries}
```

removed

The drilldown element is appended to primary chart on the first click (at runtime). So the event handlers of the drilldown chart are not linked & hence can't be triggered. (Please correct me if I am wrong.) [Trial Code](http://jsfiddle.net/rckahale/kGSXL/)

Any help is appreciated.

If the above approach is a dead end, alternatively, I will try async mode of [Dynamic Drill Down](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/drilldown) in Highcharts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advice to familiar with the [custom events plugin](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/15/Custom-Events) which allows to catch double click on point. Then only what you need is destroy chart and create new one or update series.